# Group values by same values in R

Tags: r, grouping, series

I hope anyone can help me. I have a sample dataframe:
two columns, radius and num:

```
df <- data.frame(radius = c (2,3,5,7,4,6,9,8,3,7,8,9,2,4,5,2,6,7,8,9,1,10,8))
df$num <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
df
```

The column $num has same values (1,2,1,3,1,2,3) and I would like to assign another value (sorted) per each grouped value. The outcome should look like this:

```
df$outcome <- c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), get the run-length by id of 'num' and assign (`:=`) to create the 'outcome column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,outcome:= rleid(num)]
```

---

A `base R` option would be

```
df$outcome <-  cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(df$num)!=0))
```